# Spring MVC can't reach application on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm building an application with Spring MVC.

I firstly created a Maven project with webapp archetype.

I followed a tutorial (which gave the sources code) and I can't find where am I wrong ?
The tutorial url : http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

Here is my project tree :

[image: Project tree]

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.j2ee</groupId>
    <artifactId>theaterJ2ee</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>j2ee Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOGGER -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>theaterJ2ee</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

the web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.j2ee.controllers" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The controller i made :

```
package com.j2ee.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(final ModelMap model)
    {
        // we will access this attribute in the page using ${messageToPrint}
        model.addAttribute("messageToPrint", "This is a TEST.");
        model.addAttribute("message2", "hi!");
        // Will show the /WEB-INF/pages/test.jsp
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I am trying to access the page theaterj2ee/welcome and it doesnt work (resource inaccessible).

I put the webapp on a tomcat under eclipse.

When i ran my project and the tutorial project on the tomcat, only the tutorial one is accessible..

Comment: Is there a hello.jsp or a test.jsp under the /WEB-INF/pages/ directory?

Comment: Hi, yes there is an Hello.jsp

Comment: There must be an exception in the tomcat logs when you try to access the welcome page, could you post it?

Comment: Right click your project, go to properties, and web project settings. What is the `context root`?

Answer (score 0):

an idea of ​​solution :

In web.xml replace

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

by

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

looks at what project : 
https://github.com/ctesniere/ColisExpress/

Comment: Hi, thank for your time :).
I'll try this asap,
The project and tutorial I used is there :
http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

I'll edit my first post because it can help.

Comment: It does not change anything :(

Comment: the controller are in the package : com.j2ee.controllers ?

Comment: is  theaterj2ee the context root ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return ModelAndView and not a String from your controller......The view will get resolved by the view resolver.......

Create new ModelAndView() object...set data in the model and set the view name.

Please refer to http://www.baeldung.com/spring-controllers for a tutorial on spring controllers